# the difference between zip and enumerat in for loop?

Tags: python, loops

The code is here, it deletes some element in a list.
What is the difference of zip and enumerate in the loop condition?
It seems that enumerate yield wrong result.

```
def delete(elem_l, del_e):
    n_del = 0
    for e, i in zip(elem_l, range(len(elem_l))):
    # for i, e in enumerate(elem_l):
        print "cycle:", i, "elem:", elem_l[i - n_del],  "len:", len(elem_l)
        if e == del_e:
            del elem_l[i - n_del]
            n_del += 1


elem_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 4, 3]
delete(elem_list, 3)
```

Comment: Why not simply search the [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/) for these built in functions to see what they do?

Comment: You shouldn't remove items from a list that you're iterating over.

Comment: Why does not "for" calculate "zip" every cycle?

Comment: @Kevin Hi, the uncommented code is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At issue here is your use of the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip). It produces a *list* of tuples **up front**. You created a copy of the original list with numbers added. From the documentation:

> This function **returns a list of tuples**, where the *i*-th tuple contains the *i*-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables.

*Emphasis mine*.

Thus, altering the `elem_l` in the loop does not affect the loop iteration count.

`enumerate()` on the other hand produces indices *on demand*, and as the `elem_l` list is deleted from, there are fewer elements to produce. You'd get the same outcome if you produced a copy of `elem_l` instead:

```
for i, e in enumerate(elem_l[:]):
```

where the `[:]` identity slice produces a new list, independent of the original `elem_l` list you then delete from in the loop.